# Add label with names of the variables using expss

Tags: r, variables, label, expss

I have a data frame with 383 variables. Because the names of the variables are long and self-explanatory, I would like to add these names to the labels of variables, then in a second step (already successfully done), I would rename variables for easier coding. I have tried the following with the error:

```
library(expss)

REGCON_CA_FIRM <- apply_labels(REGCON_CA_FIRM,names(REGCON_CA_FIRM)<-names(REGCON_CA_FIRM))

# Error in if (curr_name %in% data_names) { : argument is of length zero
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data via `dput()`.

Comment: data("mtcars") will do the trick, I just want to add the names of the variables as labels of the variable. Let me know if that is ok.

Comment: Can you add the desired output in your post for further clarification, thank you.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I assumed you’re using expss? If not, please [edit] your post with the correct package, as `apply_labels()` isn’t a base R function.

Answer (score 3):

A one-liner using `mtcars`:

```
do.call(apply_labels, c(list(data=mtcars),setNames(names(mtcars), names(mtcars)) %>% as.list()))
```

However, for your use case, you can create a small function as below that takes a dataframe and a vector of new names, and basically moves the current column names to labels, and replaces the original (i.e. too long) names with the new names

```
replace_long_with_short <- function(d,short_names) {
  setNames(
    do.call(apply_labels, c(list(data=d),setNames(names(df), names(df)) %>% as.list())),
    short_names
  )
}
```

Pass your dataframe to this function, along with desired new names. The function will return the frame with the original column names as labels, and the new colnames will be the desired new names:

Example: Let's say you have a data frame that looks like this:

```
  X.is.an.important.variable Y.is.also.important
1               -0.003643385           1.1052905
2                1.641458152           0.5303247
3               -1.058337452           0.5490569
```

and you want those descriptive column names to be the labels, and the new names to be `x` and `y`.

Then calling the above function like this:

```
df = replace_long_with_short(df,c("x", "y"))
```

will convert `df` to this:

```
             x         y
1 -0.003643385 1.1052905
2  1.641458152 0.5303247
3 -1.058337452 0.5490569
```

and the labels will be attached:

```
str(df)

'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x:Class 'labelled' num  -0.00364 1.64146 -1.05834
   .. .. LABEL: X.is.an.important.variable 
 $ y:Class 'labelled' num  1.105 0.53 0.549
   .. .. LABEL: Y.is.also.important
```